# Java causing kernel panic

Tags: java, kernel, kernel-panic

I'm running quite a lot of computations on `Ubuntu 12.04 (3.8.0-35-generic)`, application is written in Java (`Oracle 1.7.0_45-b18`) on a server which has 12 AMD cores. Typically the computations uses 10 threads, sometimes the load average in `htop` looks like this: `13.46, 13.01, 13.07`. But usually the numbers are lower.

Anyway, last week one machine freezed, I wasn't able to connect over ssh, from remote console I took this screenshot, rebooted.

[image: java kernel panic]

There was nothing interesting in system logs. Today another machine with very same configuration did the same.

Is there a way how to debug kernel panic?

Comment: There's a lot of different things that could cause this...including hardware issues. Have you recently installed new hardware? Upgraded the kernel?

Comment: It's kernel panic in interrupt context - most likely `java` is not a culprit there - just interrupt happen to strike in the middle of `java` execution.

Comment: No new hardware, but there was a security kernel update `3.8.0-35.52~precise1` and the crash occurred on the same day (machine wasn't rebooted afterwards). I've enabled only unattened security updates but it was probably a mistake. What do you think?